# 2d Bullet game in Java

Tags: java, optimization, lag

I'm trying to create a bullet hell type game similar to Touhou in Java.

I need some help getting started, like an example to follow. I tried my hand in it making it from scratch using JFrame, but my main problem is lag when creating bullets.

I have a bullet class, with parameters to make it go from A to B. But whenever the program creates or removes bullet objects (which are stored in an ArrayList) it freezes for a tiny fraction of a second, but this becomes very pronounced when there are many bullets.

Am I doing it wrong to use an ArrayList here? What guides are recommended to learn how to do this properly?

Here is my Bullet class:

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;

    public class Bullet
    {
      double x,y, xend, yend;
      int width, height;
      int life = 200;
      private static final double speed = 8;
      double dirX, dirY;

      public Bullet(double x, double y, double xend, double yend, int width, int height)
      {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.xend = xend;
        this.yend = yend;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        dirX = speed*Math.cos(getAngle());
        dirY = speed*Math.sin(getAngle());
      }

      public double getAngle()
      {
        double angle = (double) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yend-y, xend - x));

        if(angle < 0){
            angle += 360;
        }
        System.out.println(angle);

        return Math.toRadians(angle);
      }

      public void tick()
      {
        life--;
        x+=dirX;
        y+=dirY;
      }

      public void draw (Graphics g)
      {
        g.fillRect((int) Math.round(this.x),(int) Math.round(this.y),this.width,this.height); 
      }
    }
```

And this is the code that is run when the user creates a bullet. It uses the mouseListener for the xend yend coordinates - finding the bullet's destination.

```
    public void fireNormal(double xend, double yend)
       {
          Bullet bullet= new Bullet (x,y,xend,yend,5,5);
          firedBullets.add(bullet);
        }
      }
```

I'm using a timer to refresh the game but it still isn't at a consistent speed because of the freezes.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] .

Comment: You might need to show some code. Are you using JBullet, or the Bullet library?

Comment: I've added some code.

Comment: Can you also show us the code where you remove a bullet?

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList.add()` should usually be extremely fast. Occasionally, when the implementation has to add new capacity, it will allocate a new backing array, copy the data from one to the other, before continuing. You can avoid this by specifying a suitable initial capacity in the `ArrayList(int initialCapacity)` constructor.

However you would need tens of thousands of entries for this to take long enough to add noticeable game lag.

`ArrayList.remove(int index)` has to shift all the entries above the removed item, down the backing array by one slot. However, this is highly optimised at the CPU level, and again should not add noticeable game lag unless you have tens of thousands of bullets.

`ArrayList.remove(Object o)` has to examine every element in turn, and run `equals()` on each one, until it finds the target element. Avoid this!

---

It's *possible* that the pauses you are seeing are due to *garbage collection*, and this could be because you're creating thousands of short-lived `Bullet` objects. These last from the moment they're fired until they go off screen. When they go out of scope, they remain in memory until the GC has to clear up thousands of them.

You could avoid this by maintaining an *object pool* of Bullets. There are libraries with object pool implementations, or you can roll your own using Collections.

In environments with tight memory constraints (like 8 bit games consoles) it's necessary to ensure a game runs within fixed memory, and this is similar to the kinds of things programs on those platforms would do.

---

**However** you should prove what your issue is, before trying to fix it, and for that you need to use a *profiler* such as VisualVM. This will show you where your execution is spending its time, and how it is using memory. Garbage collection in modern Java is very high-performing in most circumstances, though - don't assume it's the problem.